# Is there a numpy shortcut for generating array of floats within a desired limit?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random

If I need an array containing 5 rows of 2 floating point numbers whose values are between 0 and 100, I would normally do this:

```
coordinates = 100 * np.random.rand(10, 2)
```

It would produce something similar to the following output:

```
array([[ 18.12298022,  23.06041984],
       [ 79.29855044,  25.41550915],
       [ 79.61747255,  35.09879784],
       [ 63.75090875,  95.88711405],
       [ 23.87727443,  97.02211991]])
```

This computation requires generating the random sequence first and then multiplying it with the desired upper limit (100). Is there a builtin function in numpy's random library that can do this (presumably faster)? I couldn't find one from the docs.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you want

```
np.random.uniform(0,100,(5,2))
```

Comment: whoops ... for some reason I had 2 being stuck in my head as his target max :P